# Why pandas.DataFrame.to_csv write an extra \n in the columns with arrays spliting the row?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

pandas library doesn´t write csv in a correct form with a column of arrays

My dataframe is 
`df_with_genres_and_rating.head()`

```
 movieId                                             genres  userId  rating
0      227  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fanta...       2     4.0
1      227  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fanta...       5     5.0
2      227  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fanta...       7     4.0
3      227  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fanta...       9     4.0
4      227  [Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fanta...      10     4.5
```

when i use 
`df_with_genres_and_rating["genres"][:2].to_csv("Borrar4.csv",header=False,index=False)`

the result is

```
"['Adventure' 'Animation' 'Children' 'Comedy' 'Fantasy' 'null' 'null'
 'null' 'null' 'null']"
"['Adventure' 'Animation' 'Children' 'Comedy' 'Fantasy' 'null' 'null'
 'null' 'null' 'null']"
```

spliting the arrays in two rows.

The result that I want is

```
"['Adventure' 'Animation' 'Children' 'Comedy' 'Fantasy' 'null' 'null' 'null' 'null' 'null']"
"['Adventure' 'Animation' 'Children' 'Comedy' 'Fantasy' 'null' 'null' 'null' 'null' 'null']",
```

Is there a form using pandas to avoid this.

Comment: If your code is as posted, the output should be:


line1: 227,"['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']",2,4.0
line2: 227,"['Adventure', 'Animation', 'Children', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null']",5,5.0


--- No splitting. Also note the commas in the middle, I think you probably have extra code in the middle that changed the data in some way.

Comment: Thanks @NeilZ I check the code and I had an extra \n in my code because the function numpy.pad() that add an extra \n in the arrays. I already solve it.